# raspberry boost lib serial port read asynchronously

Tags: c++, boost, raspberry-pi

I tried to implement the serial with the library boost.
The problem is that the first time, and only the first time, when I try to read asynchronously the program remains blocked. I have seen several examples, but could not find the problem.
If I open the serial port, then close it and then reopen it all goes at first time. Why?

I use boost 1.50, g++ 4.7 and this is the function code

```
class SIM900
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::serial_port port;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
    size_t read_timeout;        // Timeout lettura in ms
    bool read_error;
    void init_module();
    void read_complete(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred);
    void time_out(const boost::system::error_code& error);
public:
    SIM900(std::string port_name="/dev/ttyAMA0", unsigned int speed=115200, size_t timeout=500);
    SIM900(const SIM900& p) = delete;
    SIM900(const SIM900&& p) = delete;
    SIM900& operator=(const SIM900& p) = delete;
    SIM900& operator=(const SIM900&& p) = delete;
    //std::string read();
    bool read(std::string &cmd);
    void write(const std::string text);
    void sendcommand(std::string text);
    ~SIM900();
};

void SIM900::read_complete(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    read_error = (error || bytes_transferred == 0);
    timer.cancel();
}

void SIM900::time_out(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    //o timeout
    if(error)
    {
        return;
    }
    // In caso di timeout cancello la lettura
    port.cancel();
}

bool SIM900::read(std::string &cmd)
{
    char c;
    cmd = "";

    // Reset port
    port.get_io_service().reset();

    for(;;)
        {
        timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(read_timeout));
                timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SIM900::time_out, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        boost::asio::async_read(port, boost::asio::buffer(&c, 1), boost::bind(&SIM900::read_complete, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));


        // Leggo
        port.get_io_service().run();
        if(read_error)
        {
            cmd = "";
            return false;
        }

        switch(c)
        {
            case '\r':
            break;
            case '\n':
                return true;
            default:
                cmd+=c;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Paolo. Your question unfortunately doesn't fit this site's question model: you should check out the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read up on [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You need to post your code. I would also include the version of the Boost library that you're using, as well as compiler and OS.

Comment: Thanks. I have add code.